# Buttons on ApplicationBar (WP7)

Tags: windows-phone-7

If you open settings of wifi and choose any network you will see Password textbox and BUTTONS (not icons) in ApplicationBar. How it is made? Is it some kind of ApplicationBar template? Or it is some Border control, but how to show a Border above the SIP(keyboard)?
Any ideas how to make the same thing?[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What are you describing was not created using Silverlight (all the "hero" applications are done in C++) and are therefore not limited by the current SL feature set.

In relation to your actual question, it is not possible to template the ApplicationBar nor is it even possible to determine when the SIP is displayed (or what its height is).

In short, I'd stick to icons if you want your application to work well across devices.